# Set XTick in MATLAB subplot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to set the `XTick` for each of my subplot. After reading [the MATLAB documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html), I decided to do the following, but it is not working.

**MWE**

```
subplot(2, 1, 1);
gca.XTick = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];
subplot(2, 1, 2);
gca.XTick = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];
```

My MATLAB version is

```
>> version

ans =

8.4.0.150421 (R2014b)
```

Comment: Which Matlab version do you have?

Comment: Maybe you need to assign to a temporary variable (`ax` in the documentation example)? I can't test it, because this is new syntax in Matlab 2014b. Or try the old syntax: `set(gca, 'XTick', [0, 6, 12, 18, 24])`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you! Your old syntax works. I tried a temporary variable as in the documentation, and it is not working.

Comment: Either syntax will work, as long as it's done in a workspace in which `gca.XTick = ...` has *not* already been done (or, rather, seen); that assignment creates a local `gca` variable that shadows the `gca` function. Quirk of the M-code parser and syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `gca` directly as though it were a handle reference on the left hand side of an assignment operation. You can use either the `set(gca, ...)` syntax or `ax = gca; ax.XTick ...`, but only if you avoid the `gca.Whatever = ...` syntax, which will break `gca` in the workspace you do it in due to identifier shadowing.

The syntax

```
gca.XTick = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];
```

will not do what you want. Instead of calling the `gca()` function, this creates a new local variable called `gca` and populates it with a struct that has a field named `XTick`. Not only does this not set the ticks in the plot, but the new variable masks the `gca` function, so subsequent calls to `gca` in the same workspace will not work until a `clear` or a restart is done (they'll just access the local struct fields instead).

Using a temporary variable like this

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];
```

should work, *as long as you have not already done* a `gca.XTick = ...` assignment in that workspace, or do one anywhere in the same function.

This is an unfortunate quirk of how Matlab's take on the "uniform access principle" works: you can call an argumentless function or method without parentheses (like `set(gca, 'XTick', ...)`), but *only* if you do not also use that same identifier as an lvalue in an assignment statement in the same function, which causes the parser to identify it as a local variable instead of a function call.

In short, don't put `gca` on the left hand side of a `=` assignment operation, and it should work.

### Demonstration

You can see this in action using `whos` or `which`. Throw the code in a function so it gets a clean workspace and use `which` to see what `gca` resolves to.

```
function darnit_gca()

disp('gca is:');
which gca

subplot(2, 1, 1);
gca.XTick = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];
subplot(2, 1, 2);
gca.XTick = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];

disp('now gca is:');
which gca
```

When you run `darnit_gca`, you can see the resolution of `gca` change once you use it as an lvalue.

```
>> darnit_gca
gca is:
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/gca)
now gca is:
gca is a variable.
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been bit by this enough times myself. (It also happens when you try to assign a value to a `Constant` class member: instead of changing the value or throwing an error, it creates a local `struct` variable that shadows the whole class. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ )